# Using jqgrid, Is there anyway to show a loading overlay while the dropdown are being loaded on the editPopup?

Tags: jquery, ajax, jqgrid, loading

I have cases where it takes a few seconds for the dropdowns to be populated on the editPopup of jqGrid.  What is the best way to showing some loading message (similar to the loading message that pops up when the regular form is being loaded)

For an example, if this is a column in my grid

```
 { name: "Parent", index: "Parent", width: 250, editable: true, edittype: "select", editoptions: { dataUrl: "/OrganisationalUnit/GetSelectData" }, editrules: { required: false} },
```

and the dataUrl (in this case: dataUrl: "/OrganisationalUnit/GetSelectData" )

takes a long time to load, right now, before the data comes back from this method, it just looks like there is an empty populated dropdown and there is no visual indicator that something is loading  .

Answer (score 0):

If you use `dataUrl` in form editing then jqGrid calls internally `$.jgrid.createEl` method which makes `$.ajax` request to `dataUrl` (see [the code fragment](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.5.4/js/grid.common.js#L353-L391)). The `$.ajax` don't use `beforeSend` or `complete` callbacks and it uses `context` option with `elem` property which represent `<select>` been filled.

So my suggestion is to use `ajaxSelectOptions` option of jqGrid with `beforeSend` and `complete` callbacks. Inside of `beforeSend` callback you can create some `<div>` or `<span>` with some loading animation. The are a lot of ways how to implement the animation starting with simple gif till the usage of CSS3 [animation](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation.asp) and [@keyframes](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-keyframes.asp) like it do [nprogress](http://ricostacruz.com/nprogress/) (see [here](https://github.com/rstacruz/nprogress/blob/v0.1.2/nprogress.css#L45-L80)).

I used [ui-anim_basic_16x16.gif](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.2/themes/smoothness/images/ui-anim_basic_16x16.gif) from jQuery UI 1.8.2 to define the following CSS class:

```css
.my-select-loading {
    background: white url('ui-anim_basic_16x16.gif') right center no-repeat;
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
    margin-left: .5em;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

The option `ajaxSelectOptions` of jqGrid I defined as so

```
ajaxSelectOptions: {
    beforeSend: function () {
        var context = this;
        if (context.elem) { // if it called by $.jgrid.createEl
            context.loading = true;
            setTimeout(function () {
                if (context.loading) {
                    $("<span>").addClass("my-select-loading")
                        .insertAfter($(context.elem));
                }
            }, 50);
        }
    },
    complete: function() {
        if (this.elem) {
            this.loading = false;
            var $span = $(this.elem).next("span.ui-autocomplete-loading");
            $span.remove();
        }
    }
}
```

The above code append `<select>` with empty `<span>` element having the class `my-select-loading`. We do this only if the server don't respond on `dataUrl` during 50ms (see the option 50 of `setTimeout`). Inside of `complete` called both in case of failure as well as in case of success response on `dataUrl`. As the result the user will see something like

[image]

The above code is just an example of the implementation. It would be probably better to create animation element with `position: absolute`. To have good look in case of usage the above code the `width` of the form should be large enough to display the inserted `<span>` with the animation gif.

Comment: I was thinking just a single loading icon (instead of one per dropdown) but this is another option as well.  The issue i have with this option is that i am using Width: auto so the form is only as wide as the largest dropdown (so the loading image doesn't show up)